# javaagent can not shut down when tomcat exits

Tags: javaagents

in javaagent start a Thread.
but tomcat exit ,javaagent can not shut down.
When the application exits, the JVM does not, because my agent is holding it up.

```
public MyTransformer(Instrumentation ins){
    instrumentation = ins;
    Thread thread = new TransformClassThread(ins);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
 }
```

run method in TransformClassThread

```
public void run() {
  while (true){
      try {
          //do something
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      }catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `new MyThread(ins,this).start();` seems suspicious. Try `var t = new MyThread(ins,this); t.setDaemon(true); t.start();` instead.

Comment: I try. But still.

Comment: I fix it.
The reason is another thread in another jar.